# Can we make facebook application using Adobe Air

Tags: apache-flex, facebook, mobile, air

I know that we can make application using Adobe air that will run on mobile, desktop and web environments. Can we deploy same application on facebook? like we do with other flash applications.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I know that we can make application
>   using Adobe air that will run on
>   mobile, desktop and web environments.

That is not accurate.  Adobe AIR applications will not run in a web (AKA Browser) based environment.  You can reuse the code you use to create an Adobe AIR application--often very easily--to also create a browser based application.  But, that is not the same as running an Adobe AIR Application in a web environment.

> Can we deploy same application on
>   facebook? like we do with other flash
>   applications.

Well, I do not expect you'd be able to deploy an AIR based application to facebook; as facebook is a web site.  But, yes you can deploy a Flash Application (SWF) to Facebook.